# Pandas chunk merging dataframes issue

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I wanted to create a chunk loading function but when I merge and concat all the chunks its size is way more than expected.

Code:

```
def merge_chunk(df1,df2,chunksize=10000,logger=None,**kwargs):
 """
    Merging 2 DataFrames in chunks
 
    Args:
        df1 : First DataFrame
        df2 : Second DataFrame
        chunksize : chunksize to merge
        logger : logger
    Returns:
        df : merged DataFrame
    """
 if df1.shape[0] > df2.shape[0]:
 df1,df2 = df2,df1

 merge_on = set(df1.columns) & set(df2.columns)
 if not merge_on:
 raise ValueError("No common columns to merge on") 
 
 list_df = [df2[i:i+chunksize] for i in range(0, df2.shape[0],chunksize)]
 if logger:
 logger.info(f'Size of chunk: {chunksize}')
 logger.info(f'Number of chunks: {len(list_df)}')
 
 merged_chunks = []

 for chunk in list_df:
     merged_chunk = pd.merge(df1, chunk, **kwargs)
     merged_chunks.append(merged_chunk)

 res = pd.concat(merged_chunks,ignore_index=True)
 return res
```

Tried working with different ways of merging chunks and also just concating dataframes after looping each chunk, but all produced the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply interative merging strategy over your chunks.

Additionally you can free extra objects with garbage collection. It helps sometimes with massive loads with SqlAlchemy+Pandas.

```py
   import pandas as pd
   import gc # if you want to control garbage collection

   _df = pd.DataFrame()
   for df in  chunks:
      _df = pd.concat((_df, df), ignore_index=True)
      gc.collect() # extra step, usually not necessary

   _df = _df.reset_index(drop=True)
   
   return _df   # merged DataFrame
```